# Automatically inherit arguments from a generic function

Tags: typescript

Assuming I have an object that contains functions returning numbers:

```
const obj = {
  foo() { return 1; }
  bar() { return 2; }
  baz(num: number) { return num; }
}
```

And `typeof obj` should return something like:

```
{
   foo: () => number;
   bar: () => number;
   baz: (num: number) => number;
}
```

Right now I need to build a type filter in which if I pass the `typeof` above, it should return an object type with the same functions but all returning `void`:

```
// Passing object type to filter
Filter<typeof obj>      

// Result
{
   foo: () => void;
   bar: () => void;
   baz: (num: number) => void;
}
```

I was able to build one that returns an object type of all the same functions returning `void`:

```
export type Filter<O extends { [key: string]: (...args: any[]) => number }> = {
  [K in keyof O]: (...args: any[]) => void;
}
```

But my problem right now is telling the new type to automatically inherit arguments. Right now the argument is any[] and doesn't give any type check.

```
// Not an error, but not desirable
{
   foo: (...args: any[]) => void;
   bar: (...args: any[]) => void;
   baz: (...args: any[]) => void;
}
```

So, how do I pass the argument generics down to the new functions? I'd really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `Parameters` type alias that is [pending addition to the standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26243):

```
type Parameters<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> = T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;

export type Filter<O extends { [key: string]: (...args: any[]) => number }> = {
  [K in keyof O]: (...args: Parameters<O[K]>) => void;
}
```

Comment: Woah thank you for the answer! This is _very_ close to what I'm looking for but Typescript is throwing a `TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.` error in the `...args: infer P` and `...args: Parameters<O[K]>` bit. Do you know what's going on with this?

Comment: You must be using TypeScript older than 3.0.  I forgot to say, this works only in TypeScript 3.0 and newer.

Comment: Holy shit. It worked like a charm. Thank you so much 